# Is it possible to make matplotlib-plot to connect sparse dots using spline without interpolation (or any other Python library)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spline

I need to draw a plot of a function that I know its analytic form. For example, `y=exp(-x^2/2)`.

If I plot this function over an interval of `[-5,5]` with 11 points, I get the blue curve below. Notice how lines connecting points are linearly interpolated, making an incorrect representation of the function. If I use more points, I could get more accurate plot like the yellow curve below. On the other hand, if I use cubic spline then the curve seems more realistic even if the sampling rate is low (green curve).

[image: Green curve is derived using cubic spline from blue curve, and projected onto the same grid as yellow.]

This is not a problem in most cases, but if I want a vector output like `svg` or `pdf`, I'd love to reduce the number of points as low as possible to minimize the size of output. So, I'd like to see if there is any option in `matplotlib` or any other `python`-based plotting library that can either connect the dots using spline, or specify the slope and curvature at each point (similar to Photoshop or MS Powerpoint).

Comment: This post seems useful: [Reduce number of points in line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573997/reduce-number-of-points-in-line)